# Using mathematical software e.g. Maxima outside of academics? For example as a software engineer?

Tags: math-software, maxima-software

I study computer science, and 1st year's maths module makes me use Maxima, computer algebra system.

Maybe that's a bit of a naive question, but who uses mathematical software outside of academics? Civil engineers? Mathematicians working for banks? I seriously have no idea, and I'm basically taking a stab in the dark.

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematical software"?  Is Microsoft Excel mathematical software?

Comment: Anything more advanced than excel (I'm aware it's quite advanced if using macros). I put maxima as an example in the topic of the question, Computer algebra systems and anything under this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_software_for_mathematics

Comment: In the era of "big data", certainly many people are using mathematical software of all kinds to analyse data. Even outside of the strictly mathematical professionals, you'll certainly find many engineers to do some (lots of?) numerical simulations.